# When I move armature on one arm, one part of the mesh on the other arm moves as well

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

Here's the picture: [image: The mesh moving by the other arm]

It's not bad weight painting, I think, since I checked all of the bones and none of them have influence on the part of the mesh.

Btw, here is the .blend file: [image]

Comment: please provide your blend file because you gave us nearly no information at all...

Comment: It looks as if you may have a disconnected vertex from your image but as @Chris says we really need to see your Blend file. You could try going into Edit mode, select all, and then Mesh > Cleanup > Delete Loose. Suggest you save the file before you try that though just in case...

Comment: @JohnEason I've added the blend file.

Comment: You have a bone named "Bone.003" which is set to deform, isn't mirrored, and won't get its VGs mirrored because it's not in .L/.R format.  When the L arm moves, Bone.003 moves, affecting verts on both sides of the mesh.

Answer (score 0):

"You have a bone named "Bone.003" which is set to deform, isn't mirrored, and won't get its VGs mirrored because it's not in .L/.R format. When the L arm moves, Bone.003 moves, affecting verts on both sides of the mesh." –
Nathan

This was correct, thank You.